# about nesting two format method {:>6} and {:.3f)

Tags: methods, nested, format

I want print s1 (=0.11) like this;
0.110

For make this result, I used print('{:>6}'.format(s1)) to make interval rightside and print('{:.3f}'.format(s1)) to make 3 numbers under the point but I can't nesting that two method
For nesting them, I tried print('{:.3f}','{:>6}'.format(s1)), it's printed {:.3f}   0.11
And I tried print('{:.3f, :>6}'.format(s1)) it's valueError

So my questions are two:
What is the law to nesting format mathod?
What I have to make that result?

Comment: What language are you writing?

Comment: My mother tongue is not English so there might be have wrong grammer or word. I tried hard but this is my best sentence. Forgive me please

Comment: I meant programing language.